# Authentication to the Jira REST API using Sails JS

Tags: api, rest, sails.js, jira

New to Sails, i 'am wondering how can i get access to my Jira account via Sails in order to create/edit/search some Issues with the Jira API REST.

I searched for this evrywhere, can someone help me please ?

Here is an exemple of what i want to do :

```
    module.exports = {

test: function(req, res)

  var https = require('https');
      var https = require('https'), options = {
        host : "jira.company.com",
        port : 80,
        path : "/rest/api/2/search?jql=issue=TASC-1",
        method : 'GET'};
  https.request(options, function(response) {
    var responseData = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

response.on('data', function(chunk){
  responseData += chunk;
});

response.once('error', function(err){
  // Some error handling here, e.g.:
  res.serverError(err);
});

response.on('end', function(){
  try {


       // response available as `responseData` in `yourview`
    res.locals.requestData = JSON.parse(responseData);
  } catch (e) {
  sails.log.warn('Could not parse response from options.hostname: ' + e);
  }
  res.view('client');
}); }).end();}}
```

But i got nothing in my View, i think it's normal because i did not authenticate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it was an authentication problem, to resolve that,I simply add in the request header the login and password properties formatted as the official [documentation](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/api-reference/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-basic-authentication) explained it, so my code becomes:

```
module.exports = {

test: function(req, res)

  var https = require('https');
      var https = require('https'), options = {
        host : "jira.company.com",
        port : 443,
        path : "/rest/api/2/search?jql=issue=TASC-1",
        method : 'GET'
        headers: {
                 "Authorization": "Basic YWxbG9wMS4zp0bWFuzeThYS5l1TIqaXoxOTg5554Jh"
    }
           };
  https.request(options, function(response) {
    var responseData = '';
    response.setEncoding('utf8');

response.on('data', function(chunk){
  responseData += chunk;
});

response.once('error', function(err){
  // Some error handling here, e.g.:
  res.serverError(err);
});

response.on('end', function(){
  try {

       // response available as `responseData` in `yourview`
    res.locals.requestData = JSON.parse(responseData);
  } catch (e) {
  sails.log.warn('Could not parse response from options.hostname: ' + e);
  }
  res.view('client');
}); }).end();}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use /rest/auth/1/session to authenticate and get cookies: https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4234

or you can pass http basic auth headers with your /rest/api/2/search request.